# Retrieve the next day not included in a CoreData request result

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdate, nsfetchrequest

I would like to get the next available day by starting my search from today and excluding the dates provided by a Core Data request.

my initialization code, and a helping method implemented in the same class

```
+ (NSDate *)getDateByAddingDays:(NSInteger)days toDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSDate *newdate = [[NSDate alloc]init];
    if (days != 0) {
        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        components.day = days;
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        newdate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date
                                           options:0];
    }
    return newdate;
}

+ (void)myTroublesomeMethod {

    // standard initialization of NSFetchRequest
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

    NSFetchRequest *request3 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *chiusureDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Chiusure" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSError *error;
    [request3 setEntity:chiusureDescription];
    NSArray *arrayChiusure = [context executeFetchRequest:request3 error:&error];

    // I then extract the "data" attribute, that stores the date to be excluded

    NSMutableArray *giorniChiusura = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (Chiusure *entity in arrayChiusure) {
            [giorniChiusura addObject:(NSDate*) entity.data];
        }

    // and here is where the problem rises:

    NSInteger days = 0;
    NSDate *nextDate = [self getDateByAddingDays:days toDate:today];
    if ([arrayChiusure containsObject:nextDate]) {

        // HERE is the error, I suppose. nextDate is never contained in arrayChiusure, so the next while statement is an infinite loop.

        while ([arrayChiusure containsObject:nextDate]) {
            days += 1;
            nextDate = [self getDateByAddingDays:days toDate:today];
        }

    // OMITTED: use of nextDate somewhere later in my code
}
```

**ALTERNATIVE APPROACHES  I'VE THOUGHT AT**:

- I understand that I can make a new `NSFetchRequest` inside the `while`
  loop in order to check if the proposed nextDate is included into
  `Chiusure` Entity dataset but it seems overkilling to me.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**:

- `arrayChiusure` is expected to contain 10-20 entities at maximum
- I suppose the error is related to a wrong comparison (i.e. in `[arrayChiusure containsObject:nextDate]`) but I do not understand why

any help is appreciated :)
thanks in advance

Comment: 1) What type has `entity.data` and why do you have to *cast* it to `NSDate *`? - 2) Are you aware that `NSDate` represents not just the "day", but an absolute point in time (including hours, minutes, seconds and milli-seconds). Therefore the chances that the array contains `nextDate` are quite low.

Comment: @MartinR I'm casting it to `NSDate` just in order to let you know that is a `NSDate` otherwise it is unnecessary... simple laziness in order to not have to explain my whole Core Data Entity definition :#) However you are right: I can force `nextDate` to have hours, minutes, seconds = to 0 in order to match `entity.data`, since it is populated from a JSON "pure" date array using RestKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in a comment, the problem is that `NSDate` represents not only the
day, but also the time up to milli-seconds. Therefore you have to "normalize" the date
first to represent the current day at midnight (or whatever is store in the Core Data objects).

<strike>However, there is an easier solution: You can create a fetch request that returns only
the most recent date already present in the store (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18395185/1187415 for an example) and then add one day to it.</strike>

Example:

```
NSArray *arrayChiusure = [context executeFetchRequest:request3 error:&error];

// Extract "data" attribute into new array:
NSArray *giorniChiusura = [arrayChiusure valueForKey:@"data"];

// nextDate = "today at midnight":
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *nextDate;
[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&nextDate interval:NULL forDate:today];

// Find next available day:
NSDateComponents *oneDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
oneDay.day = 1;
while ([giorniChiusura containsObject:nextDate]) {
    nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDay toDate:nextDate options:0];
}
```

Comment: The easier solution is not correct. What if the fetch request has two, or three contiguous dates? adding one day to the first result still provides a "forbidden" date

Comment: @furins: What I suggested is to fetch the *last* used date. - But it may be that I misunderstood your problem or simplified to much. If you want to find the *first unused day* after today than you have to normalise the date. You can improve the method by fetching only objects after today and sorting them in ascending order according to the date.

Comment: I believe the misunderstanding is in the term "used". I'm not populating the Core Data with "used" dates, but with something like national holidays for the next 1-2 years. So If I fetch the *last* date I'll probably get something far in the future and this is not acceptable as well as adding 1 day to the *first* result. However thanks to your help I reached an acceptable solution. Since I entirely owe you my answer, if you wish you can append it to your answer and I'll remove mine.

Comment: @furins: OK, I think I got it now. I have made another suggestion for simplification, but it is completely up to you which answer you accept.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin. Your answer provided me ideas, solutions and taught me a lot. Now I have to fight with timezones and daylightSavings, but that is for another question maybe :)